# How can i make a Qt Quick (QML) ListView Item unselectable?

Tags: qt, listview, qt4, qml

Can I make a QML Item contained into a ListView object unselectable? Something like this

```
 for(var i=0; i < ListView.model.count; i++) {                                                                                                         
       ListView.model.get(i).selectable = false;                                                                                         
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "unselectable" you mean to prevent the user from being able to click on the item then you can add a `selectable` property to the model as you have done, then use it in the `onClicked` event in your `ListView` delegate - something like this:

```
ListView {
  ...
  delegate: Item {
    ....
    MouseArea {
      anchors.fill: parent;
      onClicked: {
        if(selectable) {
           //Do Something Interesting...
        } 
    }
  }
}
```

Also, it looks like you are referencing the model incorrectly.  Either use the id of the `ListView` (e.g. `myListView.model`) or if your for loop is within scope you can refer to the `model` directly.